# Как записать аудиодорожку стрима?

Tags: java, mp3, mp4

У меня есть стрим rtmp, в формате mp4.
Я читаю его с помощью xuggler, пытаюсь его записать в формат mp3 в файл. Но при чтении пишет ошибку чтения файла.

```
public class TestClass {
private static String RTMP = "rtmp://name/name2/myStream";
private static String mp4tomp3 = "MP4toMp3.mp4";

private static final String inputFilename = RTMP;
private static final String outFilename = "test2.mp3";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
    // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color space
    mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

    IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outFilename,
            mediaReader);

    mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
    mediaReader.addListener(new MediaToolAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(IAddStreamEvent event) {
            super.onAddStream(event);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAudioSamples(IAudioSamplesEvent event) {
            super.onAudioSamples(event);
            System.out.println("onAudioSamples="+event.getAudioSamples());
        }
    });

    // read out the contents of the media file and
    // dispatch events to the attached listener
    while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null);
}
}
```

И можно ли получить байты mp3, до записывания в файл?